# Handling multiple JPanels (views) using MVC

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm currently building an application that will require many different 'states' e.g. A screen for a user to log-in, a welcome page etc.

I want to design this application with MVC in mind but being somewhat of a newbie when it comes to MVC so I'm not sure what the best way to handle the multiple states would be.

What I have done in the past is use one big controller which changes the content of a JFrame, for example the user would click a button on a particular **view** (which is just a JPanel with various components), which would notify the controller and if necessary the controller would switch the current JPanel on the JFrame. E.g. the user clicks the login button and the controller removes the login JPanel and switches it with the welcome page. This of course means that the single controller must keep instances of these different views and the single controller eventually becomes very large due to interacting with all the different views.

So my question is how can I implement something similar to what I described above but with a greater separation of concerns?

P.S I've looked into using Card layout but I don't feel it provides enough separation when building a large application.